# HTTP 403 Forbidden : This website requires you to log in

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-5

Using **asp .net MVC 4.0** , **razor** , **VS2010** , **IIS5.2** , **windows Server 2003**

I have built an application which i want to publish in IIS. what i did is listed below:

1. Cleaned then built the solution.
2. right click on project file and clicked **PUBLISH**.
3. publish method : **File System**
4. Target Location : **C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\testing**
5. then publish.

Then i went to IIS and got my site in **Default web sites**. happy :). Then i did:

1. right clicked on **testing**(my app) and open properties.
2. In the **tabdirectory** everything goes fine.
3. in **asp.nettab**, i set asp .net version **4.0.30319**
4. here is a little confusion, I set **home/index** as my default content page in **documentstab**
5. then I right click **testing** and clicked **browse**. And it shows :

> Most likely causes:
>
> This website requires you to log in.
>
> This error(HTTP 403 Forbidden) means that this program was able to connect to
> the website, but it does not have permission to view the webpage.

a short summury what i got as error message. This is my fist mvc application and first hosting. What is my fault here? what should i do now?

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue. Please try the following:

**A. Suggestion below from [Microsoft Technet](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/praveenh/2013/04/30/intermittent-http-403-forbidden-error-while-trying-to-browse-to-a-sharepoint-web-app/) helped me**:

The solution is to ensure that the **Authenticated Users** or **\Users** group (which usually contains DOMAIN\Users group) has **Read & Execute**, **List Folder Contents** and **Read** permissions on the **/BIN** folder below C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories{Sitename80}. Follow the steps listed below to grant the required permissions:

1. Open **Windows Explorer** and navigate to the **/bin** directory of
   your web application
2. Right-click on the folder and click on **Properties**
3. Go to Security tab and click on **Edit**
4. Click on **Add** and add the local server group **Authenticated
   Users** or **< SERVER NAME >\Users** (this usually contains
   DOMAIN\Users group).
5. Select the **Read & Execute**, **List Folder Contents** and **Read**
   permissions (if you are planning to add Everyone to the /bin folder,
   grant Read permissions only)
6. Click **OK** to apply the new settings
7. NOTE: you may need to to it *after every Publish*, as permissions somehow may get reset.

**B. In VS - set the default page for your website, or try navigating to specific page as opposed to simply opening the website with only the site name.**

I know it sounds dumb, but that also was the problem for me

after publishing your webiste to IIS, navigate to *http://myServer/mySite/somePage* instead of *http://myServer/MySite*

Comment: B helped me - there was a problem with the home controller.