# File access over https in Apache

Tags: apache, https

I am using Apache 2.4.4. I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236351/installation-ssl-in-wamp-server-error-in-httpd-ssl-conf) to get the local http website running over both http and https.

I am able to access the content via http. But if I try to access the contents over https, I am getting the error **403, Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server..**

I tried changing file permissions using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751179/http-403-forbidden-this-website-requires-you-to-log-in) and configuring the httpd.conf using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server), still no luck.

Any suggestions/feedback is appreciated.

Comment: We cannot help if you do not post the relevant sections of your http servers host configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by providing access to relevant directories rather that directly providing access to the **wwwroot** folder.